# ¿Por que me aparecen signos de interrogacion al mostrar mi consulta a sql server en php?

Tags: php, sql-server, html-tabla

Buen Dia.
Estoy empezando a desarrollar paginas html con php.
Actualmente estoy tratando de visualizar en mi pagina consultas a Base de Datos de SQL Server.
Todo me habia funcionado bien hasta que quise visualizar una DB con caracteres "especiales" la cual se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta Tabla como mencione; trate de visualizarla en una pagina pero me salio el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como comente apenas voy empezando entonces queria preguntar cual podria ser el factor que hace que no se visualicen correctamente los datos, ya he hecho pruebas con DB con datos "normales" y se visualizan sin ningun problema.

Espero puedan ayudarme a visualizar la informacion tal como se visualiza en la base de datos, en este caso que se vea el circulo y el triangulo en vez de un signo de interrogacion. Si es necesario adjuntar algun codigo de lo que se ha programado sin problema lo adjunto, no adjunte nada porque especificamente no sabria que mostrar.Me imagino que puede ser algo con relacion a la consulta a la base de datos.
Sin mas por el momento gracias!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Verifica que la BD y las tablas estén en `UTF8mb4`, puede ser un collation `utf8mb4_general_ci`. Y en [la conexión](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php): `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');` O si estás usando PDO, también hay un ejemplo en el mismo link.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Al final solucione el problema añadiendo esto a mi conexion -> $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"CVT", "UID"=>"saf", "PWD"=>"saa","CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");